# Finding when values crossover in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have used the following query to get all the values that exist between the dates (passed as parameters):

```
SELECT date, share_id, close, sma50, sma100, sma200 FROM this, that, other 
WHERE this.id = that.share_id
AND that.id = other.id
AND date <= '2014-08-13'
AND date >= '2014-07-31'
AND share_id IN (2625, 2626, 2628)
ORDER BY share_id, date;
```

Which Returns data:

```
date        share_id close      sma50       sma100      sma200
2014-07-31  2625    61963.00    62114.7200  60182.0200  55867.6050
2014-08-01  2625    61292.00    62150.6600  60248.8700  55931.0700
2014-08-04  2625    62108.00    62190.4600  60315.9900  55999.2950
2014-08-05  2625    61191.00    62218.3200  60370.9000  56064.2500
2014-08-06  2625    60233.00    62241.6000  60408.7700  56121.0900
2014-08-07  2625    59765.00    62243.2400  60432.4000  56173.6650
2014-08-08  2625    60522.00    62260.6800  60461.6200  56230.3400
2014-08-11  2625    61492.00    62300.0000  60511.3300  56286.7950
2014-08-12  2625    61450.00    62322.9000  60560.8300  56343.2450
2014-08-13  2625    61172.00    62318.4200  60594.6100  56398.4750
2014-07-31  2626    24606.00    24751.3800  24431.3722  24137.0023
2014-08-01  2626    24258.00    24752.0400  24427.6622  24142.5973
2014-08-04  2626    24353.00    24753.8400  24426.0459  24148.3023
2014-08-05  2626    24100.00    24757.0800  24425.9971  24155.1223
```

In technical analysis crossovers of moving averages are signals for possible trend changes.
Would it be possible to isolate when:

The `sma50` crosses from being larger than `sma200` to being smaller than `sma200` within this date range? Is it possible to do in a single query...find all shares where `sma50` has crossed over the `sma200` for each specific share within that time period?

I can't think of an elegant way to do this without iterating / looping through the date in a stored procedure.

Expected Result Set (if we check for close value crossing below sma200, changed the close value of last record above):

```
2014-08-05  2626    24100.00    24757.0800  24425.9971  24155.1223
```

Just to Give an Easier Example, to make it clearer:

```
date        sma200      sma50
2014-08-05  4080.4500   4022.2200
2014-08-06  4079.8700   4030.4600
2014-08-07  4079.4800   4039.7400
2014-08-08  4078.9050   4051.8400
2014-08-11  4079.3600   4066.3000
--->2014-08-12  4079.9750   4081.6600
    2014-08-13  4079.7500   4093.4200
    2014-08-14  4079.7000   4106.0000
    2014-08-15  4079.4950   4117.7200
    2014-08-18  4078.3300   4130.2400
    2014-08-19  4077.1250   4141.8400
    2014-08-20  4076.6350   4152.6600
    2014-08-21  4075.6400   4162.8000
    2014-08-22  4073.5950   4174.6400
```

Query Used:

```
SELECT date, sma200, sma50
FROM this, dly, ndctrs
WHERE this.id = that.share_id
AND that.id = other.id
AND date >= '2014-06-05'
AND date <= '2014-08-22'
AND share_id = 4500;
```

Expected Result:

```
date        sma200      sma50        type
2014-08-12  4079.9750   4081.6600    over
```

Possible Solution:

Find all where sma50 >= sma200 during that period
Find all where sma50 < sma200 during that period

If there is more than 1 result returned in both datasets, then we can say that a crossover has occurred, finding when and where is slightly more difficult

Comment: Add expected result set you want from the query

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want OVER and PARTITION BY; http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2010/10/tip-over-and-partition-by/. Do you need to know when a value broke a trend in either direction?  Or only the first date in which sma50 went from higher to lower?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select date, share_id, close, sma50, sma100, sma200 From (
    SELECT date, share_id, close, sma50, sma100, sma200 FROM this, that, other 
    WHERE this.id = that.share_id
    AND that.id = other.id
    AND date <= '2014-08-13'
    AND date >= '2014-07-31'
    AND share_id IN (2625, 2626, 2628)
    ORDER BY share_id, date) as expr1 
Where sma50 < sma200 group by share_id
```

I copied your query set into a table to test this on - you might have to tweak a few minor syntax errors with the way it's nested, but the principle works.  This will select all records where the sma50 is greater than sma200, but the Group By collapses it to only take the first record for each share_id.  Because you already ordered the result set by date, the record it will select will be the earliest for each share_id.